# Designing a customized search page

Tags: python, django

I am trying to find the best way to design the following search page in my website:

I have a database of pre-calculated measurements for a huge number of neurons.
Each measurment object holds more than 20 fields for each neuron.
The search page should provide a range of two values [min-max] for each fieldin the measurment object

For example (a simplified model):

```
class Measurment(models.Model):

    width = models.FloatField('Width', null=True, blank=True)
    height = models.FloatField('Height', null=True, blank=True)
    depth = models.FloatField('Depth', null=True, blank=True)
```

the search page should have 6 textboxes (2 for each field)

The situation is that my measurments have a lot of fields, and also are not finished yet, i.e. they are still under test and some of them maybe excluded and other may be added so I don't want to change the search page everytime I try different fields in the measurement.

So I an idea that the inputs in the search page should be generated automatically according to the fields in the measurement model, and to generate two inputs for each field.
I made a form for the Measurement model but this will give one input per field, so I had the idea of creating two forms in the search page one for the min_values and he other for the max_values but I couldn't get each of the via the POST data

the code:

```
if request.method == POST:
        if 'btn_search' in request.POST:

            form_min = MeasureSearchForm(request.POST)
            min_values = form_min.save(commit=False)

            form_max = MeasureSearchForm(request.POST)
            max_values = form_max.save(commit=False)
```

I can't specify which form to get each time.

So what is the right designing way to acheive this search functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- Make a `ModelForm` based on your `Measurement` model. (say `MeasurementModelForm`)
- Pass them as two different context variable.
  `context["form1"] = MeasurementModelForm()` and `context["form2"] = MeasurementModelForm()`
- Render both form in your template within the SAME `form` tag.

  ```
  <form method="post" ....>

       {{ form1 }}
       {{ form2 }}

  </form
  ```
- Inside your view:

  ```
  if request.method == POST:
      form1_data = {key:query[key][0] for key in request.POST}
      form2_data = {key:query[key][1] for key in request.POST}
      form_min = MeasureSearchForm(form1_data)
      form_max = MeasureSearchForm(form2_data)

      # ...
  ```

OR

Use `modelformsetfactory`

Hope this helps.